# Spring MVC Rest webservice: using HashMap in request bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have the following Spring MVC Rest controller:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/zoek", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody
    JsonExcelLijstList zoek(ZoekExcelLijstParameters parameters) {
    // arbitraty code 
}
```

The ZoekExcelLijstParameters object looks like this:

```
public class ZoekExcelLijstParameters extends NgTableParams {
    private String typeSleutel;
    private String status;
    private Date datumVan;
    private Date datumTot;
    // getters and setters 
}
```

and the NgTableParams looks like this

```
public class NgTableParams {
    private int page = 1;
    private int count = 20  ;
    private HashMap<String, String> sorting; // HashMap because Jackson doesn't like interfaces (?)
   // getters and setters
}
```

I've already configured the Jackson Message Converter:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />
        </mvc:message-converters>        
    </mvc:annotation-driven>
```

The data that I'm sending using Angular.js looks like this (as represented by Chrome dev tools, so this is not JSON)

```
count:10
dateTot:
dateVan:
page:1
sorting:{"uploadDate":"asc", "uploader": "asc"}
status:
type:
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

> BindException:org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult:
>   1 errors↵Field error in object 'zoekExcelLijstParameters' on field
>   'sorting': rejected value [{"uploadDate":"asc"}]; codes
>   [typeMismatch.zoekExcelLijstParameters.sorting,typeMismatch.sorting,typeMismatch.java.util.HashMap,typeMismatch];
>   arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [zoekExcelLijstParameters.sorting,sorting]; arguments [];
>   default message [sorting]]; default message [Failed to convert
>   property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'java.util.HashMap' for property 'sorting'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type
>   [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.HashMap] for property
>   'sorting': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I've also tried using a List with key-value objects instead of a HashMap.

I've seen many solutions where they suggest to work with POST data and a request body, or just plain HashMap's, but here I need (want) it to work with a GET (since it's a 'get' operation and not a 'create' operation).

Comment: You are sending JSON however you haven't annotated your method argument with `@RequestBody` (that or annotate your controller with `@RestController` which would also allow you to remove `@ResponseBody`). Also your configuration isn't adding anything as that should be already registered by default when using `<mvc:annotation-driven />`.

Comment: Actually, the code as-is works perfectly. The object is correctly filled in as long as I don't pass the HashMap parameter (when passing it, Spring will throw the aforementioned error)
Using @RequestBody in combination with a GET call would violate the HTTP specs since the body can't be meaninfull in such case.

Comment: You are true my mistake, however you still expect a jsonish request parameter to be bound to a map, that isn't going to work. The sorting parameter would need to be something like this `sorting['uploadDate']=asc` or `sorting[uploader]=asc`.

Comment: Yeah but, `sorting['uploadDate']=asc` isn't real JSON, so that wouldn't work. I'm actually surprised that there is no way to map a JSON object to a HashMap, since they are very similar.

Comment: You stated you weren't sending JSON? You either do or you don't mixing plain binding and JSON marshaling won't work unless you create a custom editor/converter for that I suppose.

Comment: The data I'm sending to the server is plain JSON. I was maybe not clear when stating it wasn't JSON because I meant that whatever I posted here was how Google Chrome shows it in de dev console (not formatted as JSON, but as something more pretty to read).

Comment: No you are really confusing me. When posting JSON you need `@RequestBody` you state you aren't using and that it is partially working which would indicate you are sending request parameters instead of JSON. So please first make up your mind and improve your question as at the moment I'm not certain what your question is. If you use JSON use `@RequestBody` if it isn't use `@ModelAttribute` and then it will use binding but will not convert JSONish things into objects. Both mechanisms are different and for different purposes.

Comment: Okay sorry, after two weeks I was confused by my own question.
So the thing is, I want to make an HTTP GET call, which means all data is passed as request parameters. The sorting parameter in the request is JSON and this data should be converted into a HashMap.
In this case, I would except '{"uploadDate":"asc", "uploader": "asc"}' to be converted into a HashMap with two key: uploadDate and uploader.
I suppose that if I want something like this, I'd have to write my own converter for it ?

Comment: Correct as I mentioned in one of my earlier comments for normal binding to work it would have to be in the form of *`sorting['uploadDate']=asc` or `sorting[uploader]=asc`* as that is how you should send request parameters and that is how it is expected. However you are using a mixture of normal request params and a request param with JSON as a value.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didn't have the time to rewrite your code but here is a solution i used for a different project: Just put them in a map object

```
@RestController
public class NewServiceController
{
    @Autowired
    EsbcoreServiceRepository serviceRepo;
    @Autowired
    EsbcoreRuleRepository ruleRepo;
    @Autowired
    EsbcoreRuleConditionRepository ruleConditionRepo;
    @Autowired
    EsbcoreRuleDestinationRepository ruleDestinationRepo;
    @Autowired
    EsbcoreServiceDestinationRepository serviceDestinationRepo;

    @GetMapping(value="/api/allservices")
    public Map<String, Object> getAllServices()
    {
        Map<String, Object> servicesMap=new HashMap<String, Object>();
        servicesMap.put("services", serviceRepo.findAll());
        servicesMap.put("rules", ruleRepo.findAll());
        servicesMap.put("ruleConditions", ruleConditionRepo.findAll());
        servicesMap.put("ruleDestinations", ruleDestinationRepo.findAll());
        servicesMap.put("serviceDestinations", serviceDestinationRepo.findAll());

        return servicesMap;

    }
```